# How to optimize reading all records from database in JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have an SQLite database with different car types. Currently my query is only returning the first car type that the user enters. For example, if the user enters "Nissan", the program currently returns the first Nissan it finds even though there are several Nissans in the database.

How can I optimize the below code to return all the `Nissans` in the database?

```
static void databaseaccess() {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String newreader = reader.nextLine();
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception 1: " + e);
    }

    Connection d = null;
    try {
        d = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/fake/carmart.db");
    }catch (SQLException s) {
        System.out.println("Exception 2:" + s);
    }

    String sql = "select * from selling WHERE cartype = " + "'" + newreader + "'";
    PreparedStatement p = null;
    ResultSet r = null;

    try{
        p = d.prepareStatement(sql);
        p.clearParameters();
        r = p.executeQuery();

        String cartype;
        String carlocation;
        String carprice;

        while (r.next()) {
            carlocation = r.getString("carlocation");
            carprice = r.getString("carprice");
            cartype = r.getString("cartype");

            System.out.println("This car is located in " 
                                + carlocation 
                                + " and currently sells for $" + carprice);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: use java.sql.ResultSet, example : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/resultset.html

Comment: you are using prepared statement and you use `"'" + newreader + "'"` why ?

Comment: Please, learn how to properly indent your code. I did it here. Also your final try statement is missing a catch which will give you compilation errors

Comment: beside when you execute your query in your database `select * from selling WHERE cartype = 'Nissan'` did you get more then one result, are you sure you have more than one result?

Comment: Actually, you code should return more than one car if present. Have you tried to perform the same query with a tool like [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)? Maybe the problem is not on the code. Also, pay attention to SQL injections: your code is very attack-prone. Never compose SQL queries like that, you should use [PrepareStatements with parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, in DB Browser for SQLite if I query SELECT * FROM selling WHERE cartype = 'Nissan'; ...i will get all the Nissan type cars stored in the database.

Comment: @iakko I do use DB Browser for SQLite. In DB Browser, the query returns all the Nissans in the database. I currently have 6 Nissans or so. Def will pay attention to SQL injections once i figure this part out first. Thank you though!

Comment: are you sure you are using the same db `carmart.db` ?

Comment: @YCF_L Yep! I am sure.

Comment: are you sure you have only this code, maybe you call something else?

Comment: @YCF_L I do make a call to another database in this program which stores the cars that have been purchased. But that doesnt affect this query. So yes, this is the only code I have that queries the carmart.db database : /

Comment: @ArifMustafa can you provide a working example?